# I want to write exact query from postgresql to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Below is the query in postgresql but I want to write in sql server.I am not familiar with postgresql.So I am really not getting what it is doing.

```
SELECT 
    final.division,
    final.emailaddress,
    CASE
       WHEN btrim(tfinal.completed::text) = ''::text THEN 0
       ELSE 1
    END AS completed,
    final.employeeemail,
    (((date_part('year'::text,final.reporteddate)::text || '-'::text) || date_part('month'::text, final.reporteddate)::text) || '-01'::text)::date AS reporteddate
FROM 
    final;
```

I am guessing btrim is ltrim or rtrim in sql and if it's null then o 
and datepart code is for yy-mm-dd format.please correct me if am wrong

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btrim(variable)` is equiv in sql server to `ltrim(rtrim(variable))`,  removing both leading and trailing whitespace. See [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/btrim.php)

You are correct on date_part

Answer (score 0):

btrim() is like ltrim() and rtrim() combined.  It removed the specified character from both ends of a string.  If no character is specified, the default is spaces.  See [this post](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/btrim.php)

So the sample code you posted is just trimming blanks.  The funky "::" is a type conversion, making sure you get text as a result.  So the first part of your query:

```
        WHEN btrim(tfinal.completed::text) = ''::text THEN 0
        ELSE 1
```

Is just trimming a string and returning 0 when it's empty (the two quotes with nothing inside, converted to text) and 1 when it isn't.

Your question was specifically about btrim() so I'll stop there, I think you have a grip on the rest of it...

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky this postgreSQL query didn't use functions from its much richer arsenal. It is much more advanced.

```
   SELECT final.division,
      final.emailaddress,
            CASE
                WHEN trim(tfinal.completed) = '' THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END AS completed,
        final.employeeemail,
        datefromparts(year(final.reporteddate), month(final.reporteddate), 1) AS reporteddate
       FROM final;
```